# HTTPS connect for pure C++

Tags: c++, https

Is in pure C++ available HTTPS connection for GET/POST data? I don't want use any third classes.

```
void TomiHTTP::doPOST(const string &host, int port, string path,
        const string& data, TomiCookies* cookies)
{                 
headers.clear();

fprintf(stream,
    "POST %s HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    "User-Agent: TomiTCP/" PACKAGE_VERSION "\r\n"
    "Host: %s:%i\r\n"
    "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5\r\n"
    "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-2,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\n"
    "Connection: close\r\n"
    "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
    "Content-length: %i\r\n",
    path.c_str(), host.c_str(), port, (int)data.length());
```

This sample code connects with HTTP not in HTTPS.

Comment: No, there is nothing in the standard `C++` libraries that gives you `SSL`.

Comment: Do you know *anything* about encryption? Do you want to spend months (or even years) and *learn*? Do you want to have thousands of security holes and bugs? If not, then, use a library.

Comment: Thank you guys. :)